# Basic script Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I have made a basic script that registers in a text file the date and time every time the system starts, the script works but the problem is that instead of adding a line to the file every time it starts as it should be, He adds two and I don't know why this is. I am using ubuntu server 16.04.

The script is in `/etc/init.d` and has a link to `/etc/rc3.d`

Code:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo "Booted system: $(date)" >> /root/register.log

 exit
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the script is running once in `/etc/init.d` and then again for the link to `/etc/rc3.d`.  What happens if you remove the link to `/etc/rc3.d`?

Another method that might meet your needs is to use a cron job.

Run `crontab -e` and add the following line to the crontab (if you are running cron).

`@reboot /path/to/script.sh`

If your log file is in user root's directory you may need to add the cron job to root's crontab.  If you have sudoer rights then `sudo -i`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first thing he told me he had not thought about. It is a practice for a subject in high school and my teacher did the exact same practice on ubuntu desktop and this problem did not occur to him. Now you want us to click on the server.